# Running a CPU/memory-intensive task - what coding approach is the most performant?

Tags: c#

As we all know, in software dev, we can be asked very ambitious things to do with technology.

Recently I was asked about the quickest possible way to convert 4000 documents from word to pdf. The code/software to do the conversion is in place, and it runs on a dedicated server, so the hardware is also there (this is a recurring task). But from a C# performance perspective, what is the best way to do this?

I keep thinking along the lines of breaking this up into chunks (ie 40 documents) and convert them (i.e. 40 unique documents x 1000 parellel tasks), which run at the same time. Is this the right idea, performance wise? The simplest (and longest) is a serial loop that goes through each doc.

What would you recommend? There are no language constraints so C# 4.0, LINQ etc is all available.

Comment: Do you know what the bottlenecks would be? IO? CPU? Memory?

Comment: It's totally meaningless to talk about optimizations unless you have *measured* and know exactly where the bottleneck is.

Comment: It'd me memory from when I've seen the task being run (And disk). The process doesn't eat CPU.

Comment: @dotnetdev well, if memory is the limit - throw in more (memory is pretty cheap right now); if disk is the limit - are you using SSD? The question of how to optimize the tasks (which are CPU) is a bit moot if the CPU isn't your limit... Indeed, adding more parallel work will make things like IO and memory issues **worse**.

Comment: If you have access to the code/library/dll to convert the files, just use .Net tasks. .Net uses heuristics to determine how many to run parallel, so you won't have to concern yourself with how many to run at a given time. And any time you get to use a stream for input/output, slap a buffered stream in-between.

Comment: I really like the [Rhino.Etl](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-etl) library for bulk data processing. this doesn't really addresses any of the performance concerns, but i can say this library has been a great asset that hasn't created problems for me processing 100Ks of rows. (not rows as int rdbms, but rows as int data to be processed, from any source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1000 parallel tasks? You want to run 1,000 threads concurrently? You'll spend more time thread switching than doing actual work. If you have a quad-core machine, you should run four threads, each of which is converting a single document at a time.

Probably the best way to start is to use a simple `Parallel.ForEach`, and let the runtime library worry about scheduling the tasks. Something like:

```
List<string> DocumentsToConvert = new List<string>();
// here, load the file names of all the documents you want to convert.
// Then, process them with:
Parallel.Foreach(DocumentsToConvert, (doc) => { ConvertDocument(doc); });
```

You could do the same type of thing with the TPL and tasks:

```
foreach (var doc in DocumentsToConvert)
{
    // Create and start a task to convert that document
}
```

In either case, you let the runtime library figure out how many tasks to execute in parallel.

Comment: could you elaborate on your second approach, "You could do the same type of thing with the TPL and tasks:".  I'm not seeing what code would follow next (not familiar with TPL and what can be done with it)

Comment: @MedicineMan: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx  However, in this case the `Parallel.ForEach` is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Take three documents and process them sequentially. Take the average time and multiply it by the total number of documents. If that time is reasonable stop coding and publish to the server. *You have just saved the company development costs at your development rate, for the time saved might actually be more of a cost savings than shaving off 30 minutes off of a server run it took you achieve at a weeks worth of coding.*

Otherwise begin to look into Parallel programming with .Net four and test on 30 documents and due similar calculations as above to see if its reasonable. If that time is reasonable stop coding and publish to the server.

If that time is not reasonable, then discuss using more servers to split up the work further.

HTH